# Is my sago palm still alive/can it be saved?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care

Around February there was a winter storm that made all of my sago palm’s leaves turn yellow. The leaves were removed and I think I have seen a little new leaf growth around a month ago, but since I haven’t seen any new growth.

[image]